# p:dataTable and MalformedByteSequenceException

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I receive this error when I try to add the tag p:dataTable on my project:

```
An Error Occurred:
    Byte non valido 1 della sequenza UTF-8 a 1 byte.
    - Stack Trace
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Byte non valido 1 della sequenza UTF-8 a 1 byte.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.UTF8Reader.invalidByte(UTF8Reader.java:687)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.UTF8Reader.read(UTF8Reader.java:557)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.load(XMLEntityScanner.java:1750)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.peekChar(XMLEntityScanner.java:494)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2647)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:607)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:116)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:488)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:835)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:764)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1210)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:568)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:302)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:195)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.SAXCompiler.doCompile(SAXCompiler.java:423)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.SAXCompiler.doCompile(SAXCompiler.java:399)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:124)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.createFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:305)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.access$100(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:93)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory$1.newInstance(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:160)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory$1.newInstance(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:158)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache$1.newInstance(DefaultFaceletCache.java:83)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache$1.newInstance(DefaultFaceletCache.java:78)
    at com.sun.faces.util.ExpiringConcurrentCache$1.call(ExpiringConcurrentCache.java:99)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at com.sun.faces.util.ExpiringConcurrentCache.get(ExpiringConcurrentCache.java:114)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletCache.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletCache.java:62)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:256)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:201)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:764)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at it.cyborg.cdg.jsfClasses.util.MultipartFilter.doFilter(MultipartFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:174)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
    - Component Tree
    <UIViewRoot id="j_id1" inView="true" locale="it_IT" renderKitId="HTML_BASIC" rendered="true" transient="false" viewId="/progetti/List.xhtml"/>
    - Scoped Variables
    Request Parameters
    Request Parameters
    Name
    Value
    j_idt24
    j_idt24
    j_idt24:j_idt25
    j_idt24:j_idt25
    View Attributes
    View Attributes
    Name
    Value
    None
    Request Attributes
    Request Attributes
    Name
    Value
    None
    Flash Attributes
    Flash Attributes
    Name
    Value
    None
    Session Attributes
    Session Attributes
    Name
    Value
    logicBean
    it.cyborg.cdg.logic.LogicBean@9ba2b1
    stiliPortaleController
    it.cyborg.cdg.jsfClasses.StiliPortaleController@1d62330
    userBean
    it.cyborg.cdg.UserBean@1a04a2f
    Application Attributes
    Application Attributes
    Name
    Value
    csfcff
    com.sun.faces.context.flash.ELFlash@665898
    5-mar-2012 12.34.10 - Generated by Mojarra/Facelets
    <br/>
```

Where could be the problem?
    
The xhtml page (that contained a h:dataTable) was modify replacing the dataTable and the column tag with those of PrimeFaces, the class was modify to return a List object and not a DataModel...
I saw this example:
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/datatableSorting.jsf
    
and it seems simple to add the sorting option because I must not add any specific code into java's class...
However here it is my code:
    List.xhtml:

```
    ...
    <p:dataTable value="#{progettiController.itemsList}" var="item" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" rowClasses="jsfcrud_odd_row,jsfcrud_even_row" rules="all" style="border:solid 1px" id="dataTable">
    <p:column sortBy="#{item.id}">
    <f:facet name="header">
    <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ProgettiTitle_id}"/>
    </f:facet>
    <h:commandLink action="#{progettiController.prepareView}" value="#{item.id}"/>
    </p:column>
    <p:column sortBy="#{item.oggetto}">
    <f:facet name="header">
    <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ProgettiTitle_oggetto}"/>
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{item.oggetto}"/>
    </p:column>
    ...
```

ProgettiController.java:

```
    ...
    private List itemsList;
    ...
    public void setItemsList()
    {
    itemsList=logic.method.findProgettiByQuery(); //--- a method that returns a sublist of Progetti and that worked correctly
    }
    ...
    public List getProgetti()
    {
    return itemsList;
    }
    ...
```

Thank you for your help!

**Update:** Ok, I think I understand where the problem was... It's not in p:datatable and not in p:column but in my ability to copy and paste from the web... Sometimes the space character isn't recognized correctly so I must replace all spaces with new spaces...

Comment: I wrote this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581412/netbeans-glassfish-and-charset because, perhaps, the problem isn't caused by my implementation of PrimeFaces... I try to add an edit but, as I wrote in another question oin meta, I had some problem with code formatter check...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which PF version you are using, but the one that I use (2.2) has no attribute `rowClasses`.

However, `h:dataTable` has this attribute. But I don't know how Primefaces handles this situation. From my experience, sometimes it works to use attributes of underlying jsf components, sometimes not.

The error is of course a little generic and misleading. Seems like an unhandled exception from the lower xml parsing layers.

Comment: I'm using PF3.1 and I tried also to delete all params on p:dataTable but not the: id, var and value params and the problem doesn't change... Do you have some suggestion to how I can limite the search of my error?