# Netbeans, glassfish and charset

Tags: netbeans, glassfish

Several hours ago I wrote this question: [p:dataTable and MalformedByteSequenceException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9567553/pdatatable-and-malformedbytesequenceexception) but, after some trial I note that now the problem persists also with the old version of the xhtml page!

I'm Italian and I note that I had a comment with an "à" character and netbeans gave me an error. So, now, my question is:  could that error be caused by a setting of netbeans or glassfish? And, however, how can I change the charset on these platforms?

P.S.: I use netbeans 7 and glassfish 3.1!

EDIT: the answer to the first question is: NO... I resolved that problem but I don't know how (perhaps it was caused by a space character that I copyied from a website but I'm not sure)... however the second question still remains open and important for me!